# Uploading multiple html files to ftp server

Tags: html, ftp

So what i want to ask is if you upload multiple .html files to your ftp program,
which html file will be the **first** one you see when going to your website?

Comment: The one named index.html will be shown first

Comment: if you're using Apache, it follow the `DirectoryIndex` settings in configure file to choose which file to shown up first

Answer (score 0):

index.html will be the first page to be executed.